# Can I use an array as metadata value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a product in Stripe (using Next.js + Node) with a metadata of the following format:

`metadata: {categories: ['foo', 'bar']}`

but it seems I can't workaround string-only values in metadata.

Creating a product in the stripe dashboard with brackets in the metadata value result in, when being retrieved:

`categories: "['foo', 'bar']"`

Trying to create with Node:

```
const new_product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: 'new product',
      metadata: {categories: ['foo', 'bar']}
})
```

resulted in:

`Error: Invalid value type: {:"0"=>"foo", :"1"=>"bar"} must be a string`

This confirms that the value must be a string. [The docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata) were kind of unclear as to the specific type allowance:

> You can specify up to 50 keys, with key names up to 40 characters long and values up to 500 characters long.

But I suppose I'm stuck with string values in the metadata.

What is the best workaround for this?

I know I can loop through an object as long as its keys are indices, but I also will want more metadata keys and values. String delimination using `split` just sounds like a pain. I'm certain there are more ways to effectively use JS objects, but I'm trying to go as simple as possible, as non-developers will also want to make products that follow this archetype.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** I ended up leaning into the `object` nature of `metadata`, using categories in this way, which worked fine for my products:

```
const new_product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: 'new product',
      metadata: {
          category: 'foo',
          categoryAlt: 'bar'
      }
})
```

Comment: So you're not tied to a naming scheme, perhaps you could use "numbered" key names instead as well, there doesn't seem to be a restriction on the key names other than length and total count. So you could do: `"category.0", "category.1", etc.` and you at least have the ability to group them together fairly easily as you process them.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe stores this data as a single string and AFAIK there is no way around that.

However, when using a Stripe library like the one for [Node.js](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node), it does the conversion of the string into an object you can traverse.  I created a product with the same categories as the code you shared and was able to access the `.categories` property using dot notation.

```js
const getProduct = async (id) => {
  console.log("Fetching product to evaluate metadata");
  const product = await stripe.products.retrieve(id)
  const meta = product.metadata
  // console.log(meta);
  console.log(meta.categories); 
}

node test.js
Fetching product to evaluate metadata
["foo", "bar"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
const new_product = await stripe.products.create({
  name: 'new product',
  metadata: JSON.stringify({categories: ['foo', 'bar']})
 })
```

Then you can parse the metadata object **JSON.parse(metadata)** to access your properties when using webhook for instance.

Comment: This code actually wouldn't work - `metadata` itself is an object, not a string. It would need to be `metadata: {categories: JSON.stringify(['foo', 'bar'])`. I understand that you mean I can stringify objects, but `stringify` is just turning an arrray into a string, which is what I didn't want in the first place.